# Linux IDE 1.0.6 & Nano: Problem with if statement

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

This is a basic battery monitor for a solar-powered control box.  It keeps the solar panels tracking the sun.

The Arduino monitors the voltage on the battery and turns on an AC-powered battery charger if the voltage drops too low.

It works, but there is an odd quirk.

- Actual code is posted [here](https://www.SDsolarBlog.com/files/OUTSIDE.ino). Too long to post and it does a bunch of other stuff that can be distracting.

One simple `if` statement isn't executing, as described below and shown on the plot.

---

**HERE IS THE KEY CODE SEGMENT WHERE THE FAILURE OCCURS:**

```
if (vind < vTriggerOn) {    // Batt low, turn on charger
  digitalWrite(powerPin,LOW); 
  digitalWrite(powerPin2,LOW);
  vAC=17.0;
  }  
if (vind > vTriggerOff) {   // Solar panels on, turn off charger
  digitalWrite(powerPin,HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(powerPin2,HIGH); 
  } 

//  HERE IS THE PROBLEM :  THIS ONE DOESN'T EXECUTE
if (vind > 15.5) {vind=15.48; vin=15.48;}
```

This is followed by yet another `if` statement that works.

**Problem:  That `if` statement in question is supposed to keep it from going off-scale above the top of the plot.  Yet it is not executing.**

[image]

**The two gray lines show that it is detecting the on and off triggers, but the voltage is going off the top.  This should be impossible.**

**The first two `if` statements are executing but the third one is not.**

---

Considered the fact that I hadn't upgraded the Arduino IDE since first installation.  It is "Arduino 2:1.0.6:dpsg2-4"

Tried this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install arduino
```

and it told me I had the latest version.

---

**Question:  How can I make it execute that third `if` statement?**

Comment: Still don't compile.

Comment: Not sure why about that.  But the plot tells the story.  You can see it trigger at the voltage points by drawing vertical gray lines, and the voltage runs off the top of the plot even though that one statement should hold it to just under the plot boundaries.  I know this is not a big deal, but it is worrisome..

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with multiple `if` statements. How do you know that the third one doesn't "execute"? Maybe "other stuff..." is the problem.

Comment: *I've noticed that when I have too many if statements, they may or may not work.*  absolutely not. You have a bug in code you haven't shown us. If the gcc compiler sometimes didn't execute "if" statements the world would grind to a standstill because of the amount of code that uses it.

Comment: And 3 is hardly too many. Try 100,000.

Comment: This is hard to believe, and it would be a very serious bug. Could you please post somewhere the _exact_ source code that causes the problem, together with the generated .elf file? And also tell us what versions are you using. Raspbian Stretch? The Arduino IDE that comes packaged with it? Version of avr-gcc? I would like to disassemble your .elf and compare with what I compile myself on Raspbian Stretch.

Comment: Nick, you are right.  It was indeed "other stuff" - having nothing to do with my source code.

Comment: The program you posted does not compile. I did the minimal fixes to make it compilable, then compiled it on an up-to-date Raspbian stretch (arduino-core 1.0.5, gcc-avr 4.9.2) and ran it on an Uno. It works as expected. It seems you misdiagnosed your problem. My guess is you had some issue in your code, which is not in the part you showed us. Either you fixed the bug when upgrading the IDE, or it just stopped manifesting itself (this can happen when you have undefined behavior). Then you wrongly blamed the Arduino IDE.

Comment: If the version packaged with Raspbian miscompiled code, that would certainly matter. But you show no evidence of such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a new answer, upon the complete, original sketch as posted [here](https://www.sdsolarblog.com/files/OUTSIDE.ino) by OP.

I deleted all the code that doesn't affect `vind` directly. Also, I replaced the `value=analogRead(A2)` with worst case scenario `value=1023`. Also tested with 781 and 782, which produces values for `vind` around 15.5.

**Reduced sketch**

```
const float R1 = 147000.0;
const float R2 =  47000.0;
const float constADC = 5.0;
const float offsetADC = -0.25; //
const float convADC = constADC / 1024.0;
const float numReadings = 10.0;
const float vTrigAlertLow = 12.1;

float nReadings = 0.0;
float tReadings = 0.0;

int value = 0;
float vout, vin, vind;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("");
}

void loop() {
  int value = 1023;
  vout = value * convADC;
  vin = vout / (R2 / (R1 + R2));
  vind = vin + offsetADC;
  tReadings = tReadings + vind;
  nReadings = nReadings + 1.0;

  Serial.print(nReadings); Serial.print(" "); Serial.print(tReadings); Serial.print(" ");   Serial.println(vind);

  if (nReadings >= numReadings) {
    vind = tReadings / numReadings;
    tReadings = 0.0;
    nReadings = 0;

    Serial.print("Before "); Serial.print(vind);
    if (vind > 15.5) vind = 15.48; // <----  PROBLEM - not executing
    Serial.print(" After "); Serial.println(vind);

    if (vind > vTrigAlertLow) { // Normal, otherwise below vTrigAlertLow it will send alerts in the 'else' below
      Serial.println(vind);
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("LOW VOLTAGE");  // send Texts
    }
    Serial.println("----");
  }
}
```

The output is

```
1 20.37 20.37
2 40.74 20.37
3 61.10 20.37
4 81.47 20.37
5 101.84 20.37
6 122.21 20.37
7 142.58 20.37
8 162.95 20.37
9 183.31 20.37
10 203.68 20.37
Before=20.37 After=15.48
Send to PI 15.48
----
```

The `if` works as intended. It must be something else.

Comment: Thanks for going to the trouble of testing it.  It did indeed turn out to be something else.